# How to manipulate LAN driver files to accept Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, motherboard, lan, windows-server-2012

**Problem**

My problem is that my motherboard's LANdriver doesn't support Windows Server 2012, but I've read that this is just [a check that's causing this](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1772066) and can be removed. I believe this to be true, because windows Server 2012 and Windows 8 have the same core. The link is an example for another motherboard with the same problem. I just don't know how to do this for my own motherboard: a [asrock h87m pro4](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H87M%20Pro4/). Please help me edit the .inf files to achieve my goals.

**Tried so far**

- Tried to install from device manager. Result: it responds there is no
  supported driver at the specified location.
- Tried to install from
  driver's exe from the ASROCK site. Result: no supported device.
- Tried
  to install the drivers from the intel site. Result: no supported
  device.
- Tried to install from the bios/uefi boot. Result: error
  message that the selected OS isn't installed, which is true. It has
  no Windows server support.

**Vendor ID's**

PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_153B&SUBSYS_153B1849&REV_05
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_153B&SUBSYS_153B1849
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_153B&CC_020000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_153B&CC_0200

**Update**
After semi succesfully commenting out the *control flags* and trying to install the driver trough device manager it now states (translation from Dutch):

> There is a driver found, but there has been an error while trying to
>   install it. The hash was not presenent in the catalogue file. The file
>   is probably damaged or tampered with. If you know who the vendor is,
>   you can check their site for drivers.

Comment: Did you actually try anything so far? What are the network card hardware IDs?

Comment: @and31415 I've added what you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out by a little help of Glashelder from Tweakers.net forum and a lot of trying.

1. Dowload [my own modified driver](https://mega.co.nz/#!UhgxBTqA!etZOODjR36RjULA0YDUmDvBChXxUhn-oFZz3yjPjtxg) (you don't have to trust me, you can modify it yourself folowing [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210423092158/http://nearlydeaf.com/?p=1145) OR if you have another motherboard without support for Windows Server)
2. Run CMD as Administrator
   Run these lines

   bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
   bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
3. Run file located @

> APPS\PROSETDX\Winx64\DxSetup.exe

4. Optional: turn driver checks back on

   bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
   bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF